# Help proving function is differentiable in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let function $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ be differentiable in $a=0$.
And also let:

$$f(x+y)=f(x)(f(y))^2$$

I have to prove that the function is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$.

I wonder if i can even use the definition by limit for this kind of task.

$$\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$ has to exist in proving its differentiable.

$$\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{f(x)f(h)^2-f(x)}{h}=\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{f(x)(f(h)^2-1)}{h}$$
That is what I get but how can I go further, where can I use that it's differentiable at $a=0$

And is this the right approach, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure of your functional equation? It seems to imply that $f$ is a constant.

Comment: what do you mean with constant?

Comment: I mean $f(x)=c$ for some constant $c$.  Note that $f(x+y)=f(y+x)$ so you get $f(x) \, \left( f(y)\right)^2 = f(y) \, \left( f(x)\right)^2 $.  Thus if neither $f(x)$ not $f(y)$ equal $0$ you see that $f(y)=f(x)$.  Since $f$ is continuous this implies it is a constant.

Comment: @lulu I don't see where continuity is necessary in your reasoning.

Comment: @Gribouillis  Oh, it may not be.  I didn't think the discontinuous case through.

Comment: @Gribouillis  A priori, all I have shown is that $f$ takes at most two values.  It can take $0$ but all the non-zero values must coincide.  If we add continuity this means that $f$ is constant.  Absent continuity, it could take two values.  But of course the functional equation is much  more powerful than what I deduce from it, so it is likely that there isn't a discontinuous example.

Comment: @Gribouillis  I believe I have shown that $f$ is a constant (without using continuity).  See my posted solution below.

Answer (score 4):

in fact, the assumptions imply that $f$ is a constant.

proof:  Suppose there is some $x_0$ with $f(x_0)=0$.  Then for any $x$ we have $$f(x)=f(x-x_0+x_0)=f(x-x_0)\,\left(f(x_0)\right)^2=0$$ so in this case the function is identically $0$.

Alternatively suppose $f(x)\neq 0\,\, \forall x$.  Then take two values $x,y$.  We have $$f(x+y)=f(y+x)\implies f(x)\,\left( f(y) \right)^2 = f(y)\,\left( f(x) \right)^2\implies f(x)=f(y)$$

and we are done.

Note:  Suppose that $f(x)=c$ for some constant $c$  Then we have $$c=f(x)=f(x+0)=f(x)\, \left( f(0) \right)^2=c^3$$  Thus $c=c^3$ so $c=0,\pm 1$.  Any of these are possible.

Comment: $c$ can also be $-1$

Comment: @Surb  Thanks, absolutely right.  I have edited my post to reflect that.

Comment: So you proved that the statement is true without assumption that $f$ is differentable at $0$.

Comment: @johnnobody  Yes.  It's a very strong functional equation.

Comment: Very  simple and beautiful answer. +1 Without using any analytic properties you show that the functional equation itself makes the function a constant.

Answer (score 2):

If we put $x=y=0$ we get $f(0)=f(0)^3$ so $f(0)\in \{0,1,-1\}$.

**a)** So if $f(0)=1$ we have

\begin{eqnarray*}
 \lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{f(x)f(h)^2-f(x)}{h}  &=& \lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{f(x)(f(h)^2-1)}{h}\\
&=& f(x)\cdot\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{(f(h)-1)(f(h)+1)}{h}\\
   &=& f(x)\cdot \lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}\cdot \lim_{h\rightarrow0}(f(h)+1)\\
   &=&  f(x)f'(0)(f(0)+1)\\
 &=&  2f(x)f'(0)
\end{eqnarray*}

**b)** If $f(0)=-1$ we have

\begin{eqnarray*}
 \lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{f(x)f(h)^2-f(x)}{h}  &=& \lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{f(x)(f(h)^2-1)}{h}\\
&=& f(x)\cdot\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{(f(h)-1)(f(h)+1)}{h}\\
   &=& f(x)\cdot   \lim_{h\rightarrow0}(f(h)-1)\cdot\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}\\
   &=&  f(x)(f(0)-1)f'(0)\\
 &=&  -2f(x)f'(0)
\end{eqnarray*}

**c)** At last, if $f(0)=0$ then for $y=0$ we get $f(x)= f(x+0)= f(x)f(0)^2=0$ so $f$ is constant and thus differentiable.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $f$ differentiable at $a = 0$ means that for some $\ell$,
$$\frac{f(h) - f(0)}{h} \longrightarrow \ell$$

Answer (score 0):

You were proceeding in the right direction. Just note that $$f(x+h)-f(x) =f(x) f(h)^{2}-f(x)f(0)^{2}=f(x)(f(h)+f(0))(f(h)-f(0))$$ and thus the derivative is equal to $f(x) \cdot 2f(0)\cdot f'(0)$ so that the function is differentiable for all $x$.